# Extracting data from two databases by matching the value of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

"I am writing a query to match data from one database table to another database table"

```
          Database 1.Table1:      number  CFG    Name
                                   A123   28A    tom
                                   B123   23C    sindy

          Database2.Table2:       ITEM   results
                                   28A    yes
                                    23C   no
```

If I search for Number like A123, it must match these columns CFG and ITEM and it brings up like CFG, ITEM, Results."

```
SELECT database1.table1.number, database1.table1.CFG, database2.table2.ITEM,database2.table2.results 

FROM database1.table1, database2.table2
Where database1.table1.number ='A123'
AND database1.table1.CFG = database2.table2.ITEM
```

"I expect the output of like CFG ITEM results, it's displaying nothing"

Comment: Your query seems correct (of course, you should switch to explicit JOIN syntax and use aliases). Try an Outer Join to see if your Where-condition returns data: `FROM database1.table1 LEFT JOIN database2.table2
ON database1.table1.CFG = database2.table2.ITEM Where database1.table1.number ='A123'`

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you so much, for quick response, now I saw results of number and CFG..but ITEM and results were displaying null??

Comment: Then there's no match between CFG and ITEM. If `'28A'` exists in both columns check if there are leading spaces, e.g. `'28A'` vs `' 28A'`

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you so much for quick response again...yes you right there is space in CFG column ...now I see the problem ..thank you once again for the help

Comment: Either join on TRIMed columns or better fix the data (leading spaces are worst case, because they're hard to spot)

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you for the instructions ..better I will fix the data.

Comment: Evolve. don't use [old-style joins via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @dnoeth Once again Thank you...Got the expected results ..with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I prepared your statement for testing, if this works for you replace declared tables with databaseN.tableN.

```
DECLARE @Database1Table1 TABLE
                     (number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      CFG VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                      Name NVARCHAR(50) NULL)

DECLARE @Database2Table2 TABLE
                     (ITEM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      results BIT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @Database1Table1
  (number,
   CFG,
   Name) 
VALUES
  ('A123',
   '28A',
   N'tom'),
  ('B123',
   '23C',
   N'sindy'),
  ('C123',
   '35X',
   N'no matching sample')

INSERT INTO @Database2Table2
  (ITEM,
   results) 
VALUES
  ('28A',
   1),
  ('23C',
   0)

SELECT d1.number,
      d1.CFG,
      d2.ITEM,
      d2.results
FROM   @Database1Table1 AS d1
INNER JOIN @Database2Table2 AS d2 ON d1.CFG = d2.ITEM
--WHERE  d1.number = 'A123'
```

With Where clause you get:

```
number  CFG     ITEM    results
A123    28A     28A     1
```

without:

```
number  CFG     ITEM    results
A123    28A     28A     1
B123    23C     23C     0
```